# How to write a Java code which renders nice looking colored HTML from JSON formatted code?

Tags: java, html, json

For our API, we would like on some pages dedicated to it (i.e. for sales) to display JSON examples.

So it needs to be nicely formatted, with span using colors.

We could use [JavaScript code prettifier](https://github.com/googlearchive/code-prettify) but that project is archived and no longer maintained.

How we could generate a nice looking HTML from beautified JSON code using Java?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We did browse Stackoverflow and Google and couldn't find a solution. So we end up writing our own.

I have decided to post a code we did use here (for others as a reference):

```
  public static String getHtmlFromButifiedJson(String json) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    //0 - no markup
    //1 - markup for numbers etc
    //2 - markup for puncation 
    //3 - markup for "strings"
    int currentOption = 0;
    for (char c : json.toCharArray()) {
      if (c == '\n') {
        result.append("<br/>\n"); 
      } else if (c == ' ') {
        result.append("&nbsp;");
      } else if (Character.isAlphabetic(c) || Character.isDigit(c)) {
        if (currentOption == 0) {
          currentOption = 1;
          result.append("<span class=\"markup_numbers\">");
        }
        result.append(c);
      } else if (c == ',' || c == '[' || c == ']' || c == '{' || c == '}' || c == ':') {
        if (currentOption == 1) {
          currentOption = 0;
          result.append("</span>");
        }
        if (currentOption == 3) {
          result.append(c);
        } else {
          result.append("<span class=\"markup_punct\">").append(c).append("</span>");
        }
      } else if (c == '\"') {
        if (currentOption == 3) {
          currentOption = 0;
          result.append("\"</span>");
        } else if (currentOption == 0) {
          currentOption = 3;
          result.append("<span class=\"markup_strings\">\"");
        } else {
          throw new RuntimeException("invalid json");
        }
      } else {
        result.append(c);
      }
    }
    return result.toString();
  }
```